# Angular2 Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I tried to combined all my routing of each module in one routing.ts. But i got error `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:'job'`.. I've follow the coding style tutorial from angular2.. what is wrong is my code?

Below is my code in `routing.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { JobComponent } from './job.component';
import { JobfileComponent } from './jobfile/jobfile.component';
import { JobcompletedComponent } from './jobcompleted/jobcompleted.component';
import { FullLayoutComponent } from '../layouts/full-layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',redirectTo: 'job',pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '',component: FullLayoutComponent,data: {title: 'Job Assignment' },
    children: [ {path: 'job',loadChildren: './job/job.module#JobModule' }, ]
  },
  { path: '',redirectTo: 'jobfile',pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '',component: FullLayoutComponent,data: {title: 'Job File' },
    children: [ {path: 'jobfile',loadChildren: './job/jobfile/jobfile.module#JobfileModule' }, ]

  },
  { path: '',redirectTo: 'jobcompleted',pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '',component: FullLayoutComponent,data: {title: 'Job Completed' },
    children: [ {path: 'jobcompleted',loadChildren: './job/jobcompleted/jobcompleted.module#JobcompletedModule' }, ]

  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [ JobComponent, JobfileComponent, JobcompletedComponent, FullLayoutComponent ]
})
export class JobRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: What about ambiguity?

Comment: means? @Aluan Haddad

Comment: How would the router determine whether it should load `JobFileComponent` or `JobcompletedComponent`?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad i've edited my question

Comment: It looks like you have multiple top-level routes with the same `path` value. If these were previously in separate modules that had separate routes you will need to give them a distinct prefix.

Comment: Have you tried changing `{ path: '',redirectTo: 'job',pathMatch: 'full', ... }`, to `{ path: 'job', ... }`?,

Comment: already tried.. same error..

Comment: You can't do what you are trying to do. Looking at your code in an editor, you have many routes at the same tier with the same `path`. It looks like you have simply taken the routing configurations from several `NgModule`s and placed them into the router configuration of one module without restructuring them. That will not work. If those modules were originally lazily loaded, it explains why this fails because lazily loaded routes have paths distinguished by the `loadChildren` value specified for them in their parent

Comment: I faced the same problem. The problem was that I forgot to import the routing module in the main module.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to explain what's going wrong and what can we do to solve this.

**#1**: **`''`** route is being **redirected to** more than **`1`** **routes**. It creates an ambiguity, the Angular router fails to decide **where** to **redirect** to. I'll assume **`''`** needs to redirect to **`'/jobs'`**.

**#2**: A route definition with `loadChildren` shouldn't contain `component` property.

**#3**: Misuse of `FullLayoutComponent` as a template. You can use `AppComponent` to be bootstrapped by the Angular app, use a `router-outlet` in `app.component.html` and have your template working.

Try to fix your file/dir structure and fix your module code explained as below.

#### file/dir structure:

```
|- app.module.ts
|- app.component.ts (copy the ../layouts/full-layout.component into this file)
|- job\
    |- job.module.ts
    |- jobfile\
        |- jobfile.module.ts
    |- jobcompleted\
        |- jobcompleted.module.ts
```

#### job.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core`;
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { JobComponent } from './job.component';

const jobRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: JobComponent,
        data: {title: 'Job Assignment' },
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        JobComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(jobRoutes)
    ]
})
class JobModule { }
```

#### jobfile.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core`;
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { JobfileComponent } from './jobfile/jobfile.component';

const jobFileRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: JobfileComponent,
        data: {title: 'Job File' },
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        JobfileComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(jobFileRoutes)
    ]
})
class JobFileModule { }
```

#### jobcompleted.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core`;
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { JobcompletedComponent } from './jobcompleted/jobcompleted.component';

const jobCompletedRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: JobcompletedComponent,
        data: {title: 'Job File' },
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        JobcompletedComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(jobCompletedRoutes)
    ]
})
class JobCompletedModule { }
```

#### app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core`;
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
// OTHER IMPORTS
// ...
import { AppComponent } from './app.component.ts';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'job', loadChildren: './job/job.module#JobModule' }
    { path: 'jobfile', loadChildren: './job/jobfile/jobfile.module#JobfileModule' }
    { path: 'jobcompleted', loadChildren: './job/jobcompleted/jobcompleted.module#JobcompletedModule' }
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'job', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // OTHER COMPONENTS
        // ...
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        // OTHER MODULES
        // ...
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    // PROVIDERS, ETC ADD BELOW
    // ...
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule { }
```

And finally, you'll need to provide `app.component.ts` and `app.component.html`. Basically, copy the core from your `FullLayoutComponent` to update these files.

Make sure that you include `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `app.component.html`. This **`outlet`** will be used by Angular router to render the contents of your `JobComponent`, `JobfileComponent`, `JobcompletedComponent`.

Hope the answer is helpful, happy Angular'ing ;)

Comment: Hi @Burak Tasci i try to do your example and brings me this error: GET http://localhost:3000/job/job.module 404 (Not Found). Also, i think thats is an error on your app.module: When you import RouterModule.forRoot(jobRoutes) it should be RouterModule.forRoot(routes)... i'm wrong? Best regards

Comment: you're right @AliBriceño, it was a typo error and got it fixed now. However, if you navigate to http://localhost:3000/job/job.module it will give you an 404 error. You should navigate to an URL which is defined at the route definitions.